# What's the use of ScriptModule in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, web-config, httpmodule

By default IIS loads [ScriptModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.handlers.scriptmodule.aspx) which has rather concise description. I consider removing all unneeded modules from my ASP.NET application.

How do I know if this module is necessary for my application functioning? What does it actually do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is required to have the ASP.NET AJAX (the AJAX support in WebForms) infrastructure working properly. It provides three features required by the framework:

- Allowing page redirection in a partial page update.
- Being able to call page methods instead of web service methods.
- Skipping the standard authorization mechanism for `ScriptResource.axd` and authorization web service (by setting the `SkipAuthorization` property of the `HttpContext` to true)

If you are not using any of above features from ASP.NET AJAX you can remove it.